# Outside In Viewer Technology: How to implement 'Goto Page' Feature for doc file

Tags: viewer, stellent, oracle-outside-in

We are using the Oracle Outside In Viewer Technology to view files. 
We now need the feature to goto specific page provide by user i.e. if user provide page no.5 the viewer should goto page no. 5.

Is it possible to implement **Goto Page** feature while viewing the doc file in viewer?

If possible how can we achieve it?